# 'React' must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am new to development and I have cloned a website from github but it is giving error in `<Routes> .... </Routes>` that `React must be in scope when using JSX react/react-in-jsx-scope`

**App.js**

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./Components/Layout";
import PageNotFound from "./Components/PageNotFound";
import SearchBox from "./Components/SearchBox";
import HomePage from "./Pages/HomePage";
import ProductDetails from "./Pages/ProductDetails";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <>
              <Layout>
                <SearchBox />
                <HomePage />
              </Layout>
            </>
          }
        />
        <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When running the command npm start, it gives the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
  Line 10:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 11:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 12:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 15:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 16:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 17:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 18:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 23:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 23:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 24:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 24:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: Add an `import React from "react";` to the top of the file

Comment: You need import React due to not having the version of React or above where they removed the need for importing it.